# Equivalent of const_cast for std::optional

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, option-type, c++14

My class' interface includes an accessor to an object which may not exist. Currently, it returns a pointer which may be null. I would like to replace the pointer with `std::optional` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17423662/671509). The accessor has a `const` overload which uses [Meyers' const_cast trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/123995/671509) to avoid repeating the same code twice.

In short, I want to replace this:

```
T const * MyClass::get() const { 
    /* non-trivial */ 
}
T * MyClass::get() { 
    return const_cast<T *>(const_cast<MyClass const *>(this)->get()); 
}
```

with this:

```
std::optional<T const &> MyClass::get() const { 
    /* non-trivial */ 
}
std::optional<T &> MyClass::get() {
    auto t = const_cast<MyClass const *>(this)->get();
    return t ? std::optional<T &>(const_cast<T &>(* t)) : std::nullopt;
}
```

The replacement seems unsatisfactory because:

1. it introduces a branch;
2. the additional complexity somewhat defeats the goal of making the overload be lightweight (and trivially optimized away by the compiler).

I am assuming that the `std::optional` specialization for a reference can basically boil down to little more than a pointer with added safety and wonder therefore if there's some way to preserve the simplicity of the pointer solution. Is there a more satisfactory way to write the accessor overload to use `std::optional`?

Comment: Are you sure you can directly use references with `std::optional`? Reading n3690, it sounds to me like it required an *object type*, such as a pointer or `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: Is there even a compiler that supports `std::optional` already?

Comment: You are not allowed to instantiate std::optional on a reference (the people who made the proposal thought it would be too controversial and might have kept optional from being added to C++1y).  From n3690 (C++1y CD) 20.6.2p1: "A program that necessitates the instantiation of template optional for a reference type, or for (possibly
cv-qualified) types in_place_t or nullopt_t, is ill-formed."

Comment: Thanks @Nevin and @DyP. Should I instead stick with pointers? Does this affect the advice given by @utnapistim [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422477/when-should-i-use-references-in-c/17423662#17423662) to replace pointers with `std::optional`? Is there some other alternative to pointers which gives me nullness or disengagement while avoiding some of the risks involved with pointers?

Comment: @us2012, I cannot say whether any C++11 compiler supports the version which was accepted into C++14. I have been experimenting with an older [reference implementation](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional) compiled against Clang which supports references.

Comment: `optional` is in tip-of-trunk libc++, and accessible using tip-of-trunk clang with -std=c++1y.  It static_asserts for reference types.

Comment: `optional` was just voted out of C++14 into a TS.  It will likely move to `<experimental/optional>` in libc++ shortly.

Comment: @HowardHinnant thanks for the update. I'm revising my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by others, instantiating `std::optional` with reference type is ill-formed in the c++14 standard. (See [N3690](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) 20.6.2.) Thus using `std::optional` as a drop-in replacement for a pointer (that points to a single object whose absence is represented by a value of `nullptr`) is not viable unless you are willing to copy the object by value, rather than by reference.

However, the specification leaves the door open to adding such functionality in the future. Additionally, [section 7.15](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3672.html#rationale.refs) of [N3672](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3672.html) suggests a workaround using `std::reference_wrapper`.

**Update**: Additionally, @HowardHinnant informs me that inclusion in the standard has been punted out of c++14 altogether.