# Const pointer to const reference C++

Tags: c++, list, reference, constants

How can I store const references or addresses to `const someType&` objects?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>

const int &foo( int& a) 
{
   return a;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    const int& p = foo(a);

    std::list<const int&> _list;
    _list.push_back(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you're facing?

Comment: When using std containers - the containers must be able to move the objects around.  This means that you can not have containers of references.  Const or otherwise.

Comment: the stored object should meet the requirements of `Assignable`. Since reference are initialized only once at declaration, you can have them in any containers .

Comment: if you need reference-like objects in a container, `std::reference_wrapper` might be for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [STL containers with reference to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707842/stl-containers-with-reference-to-objects)

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references or any of the many other threads you could have found if you had searched first. Also, nowhere does your example actually try to form a pointer to a reference - not that doing so is valid anyway.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7559f198968f987b

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't compile. The problem is here:

```
std::list<const int&> _list;
```

When you declare a `std::list<T>`. `T`  must meet the requirements of `CopyAssignable` and `CopyConstructible`. But neither a `const` nor a reference  is assignable.

---

Apart from your problem, solutions suggesting `std::reference_wrapper` are not good in my opinion. Since when an object gets deleted, its  reference inside that list will dangle. The best idea would be using smart pointers.

Comment: Nice remark about using `std::reference_wrapper`, definitely something to keep in mind!

Answer (score 1):

As commented by UKMonkey you can not store constant references directly in the std containers. However, there's [`std::cref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) which can be stored in such containers and wraps a constant reference. Note that you need C++11 for it.

**Edit**: Do heed [Hi I'm Frogatto's warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929158) about using this though. Unless you have a very compelling reason to use `std::cref`, it's probably better to stick to the alternative he mentions (smart pointers).